# Importing CSV to postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.1

i was trying to import csv file to postres using this command.

`copy zip_codes from '/path/to/csv/ZIP_CODES.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;`

but i m getting an error "/path/to/csv/ZIP_CODES.csv:Permission Denied".
i came across with a solution of using `\copy` instead of `copy` but its not working probably because it dosent work in windows

How to change the permission of the file.
I m working on windows7.

Comment: Right click on the file -> properties -> look around in there?

Answer (score 0):

The \COPY command should work in Windows.  Try adding the drive letter (like "C:") to the front of the path.  Also remove "DELIMITERS ','" as that's redundant since you're using CSV format.

It would also help if you added the error message from the \COPY command.